# XML config comparison to detect any new key and add the key in existing config

Tags: xml, powershell, deployment, config

I have two config files (XML) for c# application:

- `CurrentConfigFile` = this config file is from the running build on production.
- `NewConfigFile` = this config file is from the new release comes from QA team.

While deploying the new build I this issue: if there are any new keys introduced in `NewConfigFile` (xml) in new release, then I manually compare the `NewConfigFile` with the `CurrentConfigFile` to see if any new key is introduced or not. If there is any new key, then I insert it into `CurrentConfigFile` manually.

I want to write a PowerShell script which can do the above task for me. I am newbie to PowerShell and I have done lots of search on internet but no luck. Please help me here.

Comment: But then.. this sounds like your `CurrentConfigFile` should always be a copy of the `NewConfigFile` ? In that case you could simply copy the NewConfigFile over the CurrentConfigFile.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the `Get-Content` and `Compare-Object` cmdlets. The `-PassThru` parameter for `Compare-Object` will enable you to output the differences between the two files.

```
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject (Get-Content -Path "current-config-file") -DifferenceObject (Get-Content -Path "new-config-file") -PassThru | Out-File "diff-file"
```

Then you can type cast the contents of **current-config-file** *and* **diff-file** to `[xml]` so you can work with some helpful methods and properties.

```
$currentXML = [xml](Get-Content -Path "current-config-file")
$diffXml = [xml](Get-Content -Path "diff-file")
```

Assuming `$diffXml` holds valid XML (like something below), you should be able to use the `InsertAfter` method on `$currentXML` to insert the new XML data where you desire. Check the **Inserting new elements into XML files** link below for more details on how to do that.

```
...
    <child>
        <subchild>...</subchild>
    </child>
...
```

[Get-Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-5.1)
[Compare-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object?view=powershell-5.1)
[Inserting new elements into XML files](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/inserting-new-elements-into-xml-files/)
[XmlDocument Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument?view=net-5.0)